# Slide at the end of each lecture

Tags: beamer

I want have a set of lectures prepared and want to add a common slide at the end of each lecture. I have done this with \AtEndDocument, but then it only puts it at the end of the final lecture (as it should), so am looking for something like \AtEndLecture, but that command seems to not exist. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not really an end of a lecture, it implicitly ends when a new one starts.

So instead of adding your frame to the end, I would add before a new lecture starts:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\pretocmd{\lecture}{%
\ifnum\thelecture>0
  \begin{frame}
    End of the lecture
  \end{frame}
\fi
}{}{}

\AtEndDocument{
  \begin{frame}
    End of the lecture
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}
    
\lecture{lec1}{lec1}
  
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\lecture{lec2}{lec2}
  
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Although not as intended (the last page is associated with the next lecture), it works erfectly as a work-around